# shopify : I got the message said that the account and password were wrong

Tags: shopify

Shopify team,

I'm wondering if you can kindly help me with this.

I encounter the following question when using my shopify account.

website : https://docs.shopify.com/

I can access to the Dashboard. I can log in and paste the URL below to get the data.
https://vivoprint-dev.myshopify.com/admin/products.json

But if I go to this link without log-in first, I can not get the data even though I enter the same account and password.

This link is used for ruby on rails. Since the system informed the account and password were wrong, I pasted the link to the browser instead. But I still got the message said that the account and password were wrong.

```
{"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}
```

Could you help me check if I did something wrong?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for joining StackOverflow! This is not the place for questions directed to specific users. StackOverflow is for Q&A style software development questions.